# Download file from github in CLI?

Tags: file, github, wget

I'm trying to download the [`tokyo-night-storm.yaml`](https://github.com/zellij-org/zellij/blob/main/example/themes/tokyo-night-storm.yaml) colorscheme file from zellij. I thought that I just could do

```
wget https://github.com/zellij-org/zellij/blob/main/example/themes/tokyo-night-storm.yaml
```

but I got the webpage instead of the theme-file. How can I retrieve the just the *actual* file and not the webpage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to click the

[image]

raw button, and copy that link (direct link).

`wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zellij-org/zellij/main/example/themes/tokyo-night-storm.yaml`

Answer (score 1):

Replace `/blob/` in URL using `/raw/` that is do

```
wget https://github.com/zellij-org/zellij/raw/main/example/themes/tokyo-night-storm.yaml
```